# "in English language" vs. "in the English language" vs. "in English"

Tags: phrases, expressions

Which of the sentences below are correct, and why?
Which one would you prefer to use, and where are you from?

- "The course materials are only available in English language."
- "The course materials are only available in the English language."
- "The course materials are only available in English."

Thanks!

Comment: The first is non-standard, while the other two are standard, and the third is  typical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the third option.

In the first option, the use of 'English' appears like a modifier of the noun 'language' and doesn't flow right. 
The second is correctly formed and acceptable and the third is just a shortening of it.

I'm from the Midlands, United Kingdom.